# Retrofit takes too long to get data

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get data from a `JSON` file hosted in **DropBox** using Retrofit, the code below works fine, but it's take almost 3 sec to get data :

```
public void getData() {
    Client.getClient().getAllOrenjiData().enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Data> call, @NotNull Response<Data> response) {
            saveAllData(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Data> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            if (bottomDialog != null && !bottomDialog.isStillShown())
                bottomDialog.showDialog(false);
        }
    });
}
```

The file size is **48.0KB**, I wonder why it takes too long to `retrofit` fetch data, does this related to the debug or release mode?

Comment: Retrofit is just an http client and does not have control over how fast drop box (or any other api) responds. The rate of transfer of data from a host to the client is completely controlled by 1) your network speed 2) the hosts responsiveness 3) the size of the data you are trying to transfer. If this is too slow for you, try hosting your data somewhere other then Dropbox ie a cloud storage option, or in a database.